# Is there possible to make an open chat between 2 android devices using SOCKETS?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a problem trying to develop an open chat between 2 android devices using SOCKETS ( server - client ).
I have the code for CLIENT socket and for SERVER socket and it works fine, I can change messages between devices, but I have to refresh the connection always to see the message.

For example: If I send a message from Server to client, in the client side I have to refresh ( reestablish the connection ) to obtain the message i have sent.
The same for sending messages from client to server.
It works fine, but, only if I refresh the connection, and I want to do it automatically.

My big question is: There is a way to make both Client and Server listening continuously for each other??? meaning that if I send an message from server to client, the client will receive and so something with that message without reestablish the connection (refresh ).

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, I saw Bluetooth Chat Sample Application for Android 4.2.* and you can do time-reflesh within usage of the sample codes and your demand via Bluetooth.